# Pandas map returns list

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, lambda

I would need it to merge both the '`companies`' dataset and '`locations`' dataset on '`target_cw_id`' AND '`source_cw_id`' in the '`relations`' dataset

companies

```
 row_id     cw_id   cik     company_name    source_type     source_id
0   1   1   20.0    MOTHER COMPANY  filers  35791
1   2   2   1750.0  FATHER COMPANY  filers  40788
2   3   3   1800.0  LITTLE SISTER   filers  60238
3   4   4   1800.0  MIDDLE SISTER   filers  60238
4   5   5   2132.0  BABY BROTHER    filers  8286
5   6   6   543.0   NAUGHTY COUSIN  filers  8286
6   7   7   4546.0  BIG BROTHER     filers  8286
```

relations

```
    relation_id     target_cw_id    source_cw_id    relation_type   relation_origin     origin_id   year
0   1   3   1   NaN     relationships   2507504     2010
1   2   4   1   NaN     relationships   824847  2005
2   3   5   2   NaN     relationships   841281  2006
3   4   6   2   NaN     relationships   864758  2007
4   5   7   2   NaN     relationships   1288382     2008
```

locations

```
    cw_id   country_code
0   1   US
1   2   AT
2   3   US
3   4   US
5   5   SU
6   6   US
7   7   US
```

This works as expected, but I would like to make it less redundant

```
merged = pd.merge(left=relations, right=companies, left_on="source_cw_id", right_on="cw_id", how="left")
merged = pd.merge(left=merged, right=companies, left_on="target_cw_id", right_on="cw_id", how="left",  suffixes=('_source', '_target'))
merged = pd.merge(left=merged, right=locations, left_on="source_cw_id", right_on="cw_id", how="left")
merged = pd.merge(left=merged, right=locations, left_on="target_cw_id", right_on="cw_id", how="left",  suffixes=('_source', '_target'))
```

So I'm trying `map` and `lambda`

```
merged = pd.DataFrame()

dfs = [relations, merged, merged, merged]
dfs2 = [companies, companies, locations, locations]
ids = ["source_cw_id","target_cw_id","source_cw_id","target_cw_id"]

merged = map(lambda x, y, z: pd.merge(left=x, right=y, left_on=z, right_on="cw_id", how="left",suffixes=('_source','_target')), dfs,dfs2,ids)
```

However, the first iteration returns a list instead of dataframe and then I get a

`KeyError "target_cw_id"`

these are the column names I expect in the final file:

```
[u'relation_id', u'source_cw_id', u'target_cw_id', u'relation_type',
       u'relation_origin', u'origin_id', u'year', u'row_id_source',
       u'cw_id_source', u'cik_source', u'company_name_source',
       u'source_type_source', u'source_id_source', u'row_id_target',
       u'cw_id_target', u'cik_target', u'company_name_target',
       u'source_type_target', u'source_id_target', u'cw_id_source',
       u'country_code_source', u'cw_id_target', u'country_code_target']
```

Comment: Could you please post sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format __as text__, so one could use it when coding) and describe what do you want to do with the input data in order to get output data set? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using `map` wrong ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map))

```
merged = map(
    lambda x, y, z: pd.merge(left=x, right=y, left_on=z, right_on="cw_id", how="left",suffixes=('_source','_target')),
    dfs,dfs2,ids
)
```

First argument is a function, you have that correct.  The second is an iterable, you have this wrong.

you performed 4 merges, I expect 4 items to iterate over.  I'd do the following.

```
def mymerge(x, y, z):
    kwargs = dict(left=x, right=y, left_on=z,
                  right_on="cw_id", how="left",
                  suffixes=('_source', '_targee'))
    return pd.merge(**kwargs)

# Initialize merged
merged = relations.copy()

dfs = [merged, merged, merged, merged]
dfs2 = [companies, companies, locations, locations]
ids = ["source_cw_id", "target_cw_id", "source_cw_id", "target_cw_id"]

myiterable = zip(dfs, dfs2, ids)

# Instead of map
for args in myiterables:
    merged = mymerge(*args)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, post updated. The code you suggested only returns the relationships merged with location on the 'target_cw_id'.